Error with DCMTK C++11 configuration: #error: DCMTK was configured to use C++11 features, but compiler does not support them
I'm encountering an issue with DCMTK where it reports the following error related to C++11 features:
Error C1189 #error: DCMTK was configured to use C++11 features, but your compiler does not or was not configured to provide them.C:*******\osconfig.h
Compiler Version:  Visual Studio 2019,
Operating System: Windows 10
I'm using Visual Studio 2019 on Windows 10. It seems DCMTK requires C++11 features that are either unsupported or not configured properly in my current setup. How can I resolve this issue? Should I adjust compiler settings, or is there a specific configuration within DCMTK that needs to be addressed?
Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
I expected that by enabling C++11 features in Visual Studio 2019, DCMTK would compile without encountering the "#error" related to C++11 feature support. Specifically, I expected the compiler to provide the necessary C++11 support as required by DCMTK's configuration.

Visual Studio 2019 defaults to c++14 so you should not have to make any change. I have used DCMTK for several years with this compiler.

Maybe this forum post points to the reason for your problem: https://forum.dcmtk.org/viewtopic.php?p=21381&sid=2663ed24e716427f3884d550e93be9cd#p21381 do you have /Zc:__cplusplus enabled? There is further explanation here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/zc-cplusplus?view=msvc-170#remarks

Sure, here's a refined version of your reply:


Yes, Visual Studio 2019 defaults to C++14. I've pulled the code from the DCMTK repository and built it using C++14.


I've also attempted to use your shared method, but unfortunately, it didn't work for me.
Could you please provide the build process details or any specific steps that might help resolve this?



In your own project that uses DCMTK do you have the /Zc:__cplusplus switch enabled?

Thank you for the suggestion. I'm still working on resolving the issue, but in the meantime, we have installed Ubuntu Linux and have been working on it there. I'll continue to try your suggestions and will update if I make any progress. Thanks again for your help!
